# How to use method that includes a switch statement in a void method

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app that encrypts a string of text using the age-old Caesar Cipher.

To be more specific, the user will type whatever length of string into the EditText View and press a button that will encrypt the string of text. The button, when pressed, has to encrypt the string and then print it onto a TextView.

Here is my MainActivity class (It's incomplete):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText TextToMirror;
        TextView TextOut;
        Button Mirrorbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextToMirror = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextToMirror);

    TextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextOut);

    Mirrorbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mirrorbtn);

    Mirrorbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        /**The onClick method should get text from the edittext view,
         * crypt that text using the crypt method from the ceasar chiper method and then
         * print on the textview**/

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextOut.setText(TextToMirror.getText());

        }
    });
}

//Trying to access the crypt method from the ceasar chiper class

public void cryptxt (){
    CeasarCipher lock = new CeasarCipher();
    lock.crypt();
}
}
```

Here is the Caesar cipher class:

```
public class CeasarCipher {

public char crypt (char alpha){

    switch (alpha){

        case 'A' : return 'D';
        case 'a' : return 'd';
        case 'B' : return 'E';
        case 'b' : return 'e';
        case 'C' : return 'F';
        case 'c' : return 'f';
        case 'D' : return 'G';
        case 'd' : return 'g';
        case 'E' : return 'H';
        case 'e' : return 'h';
        case 'F' : return 'I';
        case 'f' : return 'i';
        case 'G' : return 'J';
        case 'g' : return 'j';
        case 'H' : return 'K';
        case 'h' : return 'k';
        case 'I' : return 'L';
        case 'i' : return 'l';
        case 'J' : return 'M';
        case 'j' : return 'm';
        case 'K' : return 'N';
        case 'k' : return 'n';
        case 'L' : return 'O';
        case 'l' : return 'o';
        case 'M' : return 'P';
        case 'm' : return 'p';
        case 'N' : return 'Q';
        case 'n' : return 'q';
        case 'O' : return 'R';
        case 'o' : return 'r';
        case 'P' : return 'S';
        case 'p' : return 's';
        case 'Q' : return 'T';
        case 'q' : return 't';
        case 'R' : return 'U';
        case 'r' : return 'u';
        case 'S' : return 'V';
        case 's' : return 'v';
        case 'T' : return 'W';
        case 't' : return 'w';
        case 'U' : return 'X';
        case 'u' : return 'x';
        case 'V' : return 'Y';
        case 'v' : return 'y';
        case 'W' : return 'Z';
        case 'w' : return 'z';
        case 'X' : return 'A';
        case 'x' : return 'a';
        case 'Y' : return 'B';
        case 'y' : return 'b';
        case 'Z' : return 'C';
        case 'z' : return 'c';
        default: return alpha;

    }

}
}
```

Ok, so the Caesar cipher class' job is to scan the string of text entered in the EditText View of the app and encrypt the string. The `crypt (char alpha)` method is the method that will be used by the button to encrypt the string entered in the `EditText View`. Therefore, the `crypt (char alpha)` method will be used in the `MainActivity` class by creating a `CaesarCipher` object within `MainActivity`(Refer to main activity code above). This object will allow me to access the `crypt` method.

So, the problem that's been haunting me for the past few weeks is this `crypt` method. Since it's using a `switch()` statement, I can't call the method within the `crypttext` method within the `MainActivity`. This is because the `crypttext` method is a void method and the `crypt` method contains a switch statement which returns a value. I know very well that void means NO RETURN values!

My question to you all is: HOW DO I CALL A METHOD THAT HAS TO RETURN A VALUE WITHIN A VOID METHOD? I tried removing  `void` from `public void cryptxt ()` but android studio kept telling me that the 'method name is invalid' and a 'return type is required'.

Please help!

Comment: You can call a method from anywhere you want.  The return type of the method you're calling it from makes no difference.

Comment: instead of removing `void` from the method signature, like `public cryptxt (){}` replace it with char `public char cryptxt (){}`

Comment: @Lino Ok. I'll try that out.

Comment: @Lino do I need to have a return statement for the `crypttext ()` ?

Comment: @yes you need to return something

Comment: In this case it would be the encrypted text right?

Comment: @AugieJavax98 depends on what you are expecting

Comment: I'd consider testing if character is upper case or lower case just to reduce number of switch statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question

```
HOW DO I CALL A METHOD THAT HAS TO RETURN A VALUE WITHIN A VOID METHOD?
```

is no, you can't make calls like this. A method in Java must have a return type which can be anything even **void** which means nothing but you got to write there to let the compiler it returns nothing.

And also the below method is useful if it's returning in your case. because you want to print the encrypted value which is not possible if you return **void** so change it like to get the encrypted value.

```
 public char cryptxt (char temp){
    CeasarCipher lock = new CeasarCipher();
    return lock.crypt(temp);
}
```

and now at calling side just print like this.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //use encrypted value
            String str = TextToMirror.getText().toString;
            for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
               char ch = str.charAt(i);
               char temp  = cryptxt(ch) 
               TextOut.setText(temp);
            } 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do like that :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText TextToMirror;
    TextView TextOut;
    Button Mirrorbtn;
    CeasarCipher lock;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextToMirror = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextToMirror);

        TextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextOut);

        Mirrorbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mirrorbtn);
        lock = new CeasarCipher();
        Mirrorbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            /**The onClick method should get text from the edittext view,
             * crypt that text using the crypt method from the ceasar chiper method and then
             * print on the textview**/

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String str = TextToMirror.getText().toString;
                StringBuilder temp=new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

                    temp.append(lock.crypt(str.charAt(i)));

                }

                TextOut.setText(temp);

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call method returning something (method other than `void`), you need to do something with the value returned by this method, for example:

```
public int something() {
    return 128;
}

public void nothing() {
    int assignedReturnValue = something();
}
```

As you see, `something()` returns `int`, and I assigned the result of that method to `int` variable. As you see, `void` method itself returns nothing, but it is just a simple example of how to call method returning something inside the method that returns nothing.

By the way, I would suggest you casting `char`s to `int`s and adding to result of this casting value of 3 rather than creating very long `switch` statement. You would need to take care of it in a simple `if-else` statement too to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I created my custom function to do cipher for alphabets only.
In which I pass the string which I want to cipher and than it returns a converted cipher text. For more details about ASCII Please refer [Alphabetical ASCII](http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html) and [More details about ASCII](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html)

My be this will help you.

```
public class USCipher {

  public static String encyptCipherAlpha(String text) {
    char[] cArray = text.toCharArray();

    String encyptedString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        int chara = CharToASCII(cArray[i]);
        if (chara == 120) {//x
            chara = 97;//a
        } else if (chara == 121) {//y
            chara = 98;//b
        } else if (chara == 122) {//z
            chara = 99;//c
        } else if (chara == 88) {//x
            chara = 65;//a
        } else if (chara == 89) {//y
            chara = 66;//b
        } else if (chara == 90) {//z
            chara = 67;//c
        } else {
            chara = chara + 3;
        }
        encyptedString = encyptedString + ASCIIToChar(chara);
    }
    return encyptedString;
}

public static String decryptCipherAlpha(String text) {
    char[] cArray = text.toCharArray();

    String decryptedString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        int chara = CharToASCII(cArray[i]);
        if (chara == 97) {//a
            chara = 120;//x
        } else if (chara == 98) {//b
            chara = 121;//y
        } else if (chara == 99) {//c
            chara = 122;//z
        } else if (chara == 65) {//A
            chara = 88;//X
        } else if (chara == 66) {//B
            chara = 89;//Y
        } else if (chara == 67) {//C
            chara = 90;//Z
        } else {
            chara = chara - 3;
        }
        decryptedString = decryptedString + ASCIIToChar(chara);
    }
    return decryptedString;
}

public static String encyptCipher(String text) {
    char[] cArray = text.toCharArray();
    String encyptedString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        encyptedString = encyptedString + ASCIIToChar(CharToASCII(cArray[i]) + 3);
    }
    return encyptedString;
}

public static String decryptCipher(String text) {
    char[] cArray = text.toCharArray();
    String decryptedString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        decryptedString = decryptedString + ASCIIToChar(CharToASCII(cArray[i]) + 3);
    }
    return decryptedString;
}

/**
 * Convert the characters to ASCII value
 *
 * @param character character
 * @return ASCII value
 */
public static int CharToASCII(final char character) {
    return (int) character;
}

/**
 * Convert the ASCII value to character
 *
 * @param ascii ascii value
 * @return character value
 */
public static char ASCIIToChar(final int ascii) {
    return (char) ascii;
  }
}
```